# Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to [db4free.net](http://dv4free.net) but am getting this error. It was working yesterday. I was able to connect yesterday but today, I can't.

URL:

> jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true

Line of code error is at:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

JDBC driver is loading correctly so that shouldn't be the error.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android

Comment: Also your service `db4free.net` has the following line in their terms & conditions: `data loss and outages can happen at any time (any complaints about that will likely be ignored)`

Answer (score 1):

That's what you get for free. I would suggest using a different database hosting provider, or check into hosting the database server yourself.